# copy charts from excel to powerpoint via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I created a series of charts by xlsxwriter. Can you introduce a code or a way for me to copy these charts to powerpoint?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use python-pptx library to interact with powerpoint using python.

here is a example code to create charts using pptx.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches

# create presentation with 1 slide ------
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

# define chart data ---------------------
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))

# add chart to slide --------------------
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)

prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, but I definitely need to copy the same charts I made with xlsxwriter. Is there a way to do this?